# Highcharts missing information in scatterplot CSV/XLS export

Tags: highcharts, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

When exporting scatter plot / bubble chart data as CSV or XLS, it is missing key information, see for example: http://jsfiddle.net/11fum86u/

This is the data (extract):

```
series: [{
    data: [
        { x: 95, y: 95, z: 13.8, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium' },
```

And the axis titles are in the tooltip (but perhaps needs to be defined elsewhere):

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
```

What is missing in the default export is (i) labels for y and z axis, and (ii) the names of the bubbles (in this example, country codes/names)

I was wondering how I might be able to add this information to the export.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's no `z` axis in bubble charts. It's quite confusing, because all points have `z` property. This property serves to compute the bubble size so no additional axis is needed, because everything is in 2d. `zAxis` is used in 3d charts.

Please refer to this **live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/udtr0emL/

You can handle first row labels via `columnHeaderFormatter` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv.columnHeaderFormatter):

```
exporting: {
    csv: {
      columnHeaderFormatter: function(item, key, keyLength) {
        if (item.axisTitle) {
          return item.axisTitle.textStr; // x axis label
        } else if (key === 'y') {
          return item.yAxis.axisTitle.textStr; // y axis label
        } else if (key === 'z') {
          return 'Obesity (adults)'; // z axis label
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

To add another column (countries) added following pieces of code in these three core functions:

**1. Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getDataRows**

```
// add original point reference
rows[key].point = point;
```

**2. Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getCSV**

```
  // Add point name and header
  csv += itemDelimiter;
  var point = row['point'];
  if (point) {
    csv += point.name
  } else {
    csv += "Country"
  }
```

**3. Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getTable** (for XLS)

```
  var point = row['point'],
    val;
  if (point) {
    val = point.name;
  } else {
    val = "Country";
  }

  html += '<' + tag + ' class="text">' +
    (val === undefined ? '' : val) + '</' + tag + '>';
```

All functions are available in `export-data.src.js` in this directory: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/tree/b4b4221b19a3a50d9ed613b6f50b12f0afcc7d06/js/modules

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed, many thanks. Is there by any chance a way to include that additional column in XLS export as well?

Comment: @Kamil this change will reflect the Core functionality and hence the Country names will be listed twice when exporting Bar/Column Charts. Right?

Comment: @RohanKumar, it depends how your data looks like. This code adds another column regardless of what the rest of the data is.

Comment: @Fred I added listing for XLS and updated the fiddle.